# How to copy contents of one cell to a specific string in another cell

Tags: excel, vba

In B2 the value is "Item #000 - S/N: 123456" and in cell B4 the value is 17. How do I replace 000 in cell B2 with the contents of B4?

Comment: Please take the time to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then come back and [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54638930/edit) to let us know initial data, what the expected outcome is, what you've tried so far and how it fails to meet expectations

Comment: Use a combination of `left()` and `right()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the `=Concatenate()` formula

Example (Place in B2):

`=Concatenate("Item #", B4, " - SN/: 123456")`

You can add as many variables as possible with `=Concatenate()`

Also, if you want to display the results within another cell you could also use this...

- Place this into a new cell
  `=SUBSTITUTE(B2,"000",B4,1)`